# How to properly group results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a table like:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+    
| 1  | aaa  |
| 1  | bbb  |
| 1  | ccc  |
| 1  | ddd  |
| 1  | eee  |
+----+------+
```

What would be the proper SELECT statement to have an output like:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| Id |   col1  |   col2   |    col3   |  col4   |  col5  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+ 
|  1 |   aaa   |   bbb    |    ccc    |   ddd   |   eee  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use PIVOT . . .

Answer (score 4):

Use `row_number()` function :

```
select Id, max(case when seq = 1 then Name end) as col1,
           max(case when seq = 2 then Name end) as col2,
           max(case when seq = 3 then Name end) as col3,
           max(case when seq = 4 then Name end) as col4,
           max(case when seq = 5 then Name end) as col5
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by Id order by Name) seq
      from table
     ) t
group by Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cross apply` with `CASE WHEN` and `MAX` function.

```
select  x.Id, 
        max(case when v = 'aaa' then Name end) as col1,
        max(case when v = 'bbb' then Name end) as col2,
        max(case when v = 'ccc' then Name end) as col3,
        max(case when v = 'ddd' then Name end) as col4,
        max(case when v = 'eee' then Name end) as col5
from T cross apply(values(Name,id)) x(v,id)
GROUP BY x.Id
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1b76decac1a931961494fb5c4fe51b7

**EDIT**

Thank @sgeddes point out.

use just `CASE WHEN` and `MAX` function.

```
select  Id, 
        max(case when Name = 'aaa' then Name end) as col1,
        max(case when Name = 'bbb' then Name end) as col2,
        max(case when Name = 'ccc' then Name end) as col3,
        max(case when Name = 'ddd' then Name end) as col4,
        max(case when Name = 'eee' then Name end) as col5
from T 
GROUP BY Id
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e4f830ca766f240b10412351df56856d

Comment: `max(case when name = 'aaa'...` works just the same without needing `cross apply`.

Comment: @sgeddes In the op, this is the easiest soultion Thank for your point out :)